# Priority scheme with an if statement (pass one condition first then apply the rest of the elements to the second condition)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of elements:

```
element = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

With 2 characteristics :

```
C1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
C2 = [15, 35, 40, 20, 17, 45, 30, 18, 41, 35]
```

I would like to order the elements based on the two conditions. Note: order first with condition 1 than apply the rest to condition 2

Condition 1: order first the elements that C1[i] == 1

Condition 2: C2[i] >= 40

I would get this order:

```
order1 = [2, 4, 7, 9, 5, 8, 0, 1, 3, 6] # First 4 elements are ordered by condition 1 and the rest based on condition 2.
```

I have tried :

```
order1 = [x for x in range(len(element))]

for i in range(len(element)):
    if  C1[i] == 1 :
        temp = order1[i]
        del order1[i]
        order1.insert(insertion_position1, temp)
        insertion_position1+=1
    elif C2[i] >= 40:
        temp = order1[i]
        del order1[i]
        order1.insert(insertion_position1, temp)
        insertion_position1+=1
```

But I get this instead:

```
output : [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3, 6]  # both conditions treated together
```

How the code could be improved to solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code is exactly the same in the two branches (`if` and `elif`).  What your code is doing is basically to put at the beginning of the list all items for which C1 or C2 is True.  You actually need to work with two indexes (`insertion_position1` and `insert_position2`), one for each condition.

*Edit*: You can do that in a single loop with a slight modification of your code:

```py
element = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
C1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
C2 = [15, 35, 40, 20, 17, 45, 30, 18, 41, 35]
order1 = [x for x in range(len(element))]
insertion_position1 = 0
insertion_position2 = 0
for i in range(len(element)):
    if  C1[i] == 1 :
        temp = order1[i]
        del order1[i]
        order1.insert(insertion_position1, temp)
        insertion_position1+=1
        insertion_position2+=1
    elif C2[i] >= 40:
        temp = order1[i]
        del order1[i]
        order1.insert(insertion_position2, temp)
        insertion_position2+=1
print(order1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did as you told me to and I got the code working, I am just wondering if there is a way to make the code looks better. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
order1 = [x for x in range(len(element))]

insertion_position1 = 0

for i in range(len(element)):
    if  C1[i] == 1 :
        temp = order1[i]
        del order1[i]
        order1.insert(insertion_position1, temp)
        insertion_position1+=1

insertion_position2 = max(idx for idx, val in enumerate(order1) if C1[val] == 1) + 1

for i in range(len(element)):
    if C1[order1[i]] == 1:
        order1[i] = order1[i]
    else:
        if C2[order1[i]] >= 40:
            temp = order1[i]
            del order1[i]
            order1.insert(insertion_position2, temp)
            insertion_position2+=1

print(order1)


output : [2, 4, 7, 9, 5, 8, 0, 1, 3, 6]
```

I solved it.
Is there a way to make the code looks better?

Comment: I suggested another solution.  See the edit to my post.